# separating business rules from business logic

Tags: logic, rules, delegation

i just want to know alternatives or design patterns of how I can separate business rules from business logic WITHOUT using a business engine if possible.

there is already a question that asked this subject but every answer seems to have no specific answer so here is my try.

for example, for an application to a school.

there would rules like the minimum age, the maximum age, prerequisite education and etc. 
and then after a year, the school would ask for additional rules like

hair color should be of a specific type, 
the height, 
the length of fingers should be of a certain length,
the music they listen to and all that additional rules.

how can I make an application to be adaptable to these kind of changes on the system.

Comment: I thought rules and logic were synonyms.

Comment: Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/ValidateFormBusinessRules.aspx Although, it uses ASP.NET web forms, I think you'll see in general how business logic can be separated from the app.

Answer (score 4):

Business logic and business rules are really just two ways of describing the same thing.

I recommend you think about your problem from two perspectives. First think about the business objects that will exist. For example a Pupil object that has values such as age, height and so forth. Then think about rules that you would like to have applied, such as validating that all pupils over a certain age should have a minimum height. You could implement the validating as part of the business object or as a separate object in its own right. There is no right or wrong answer as it depends on the problem your trying to solve.

Comment: phil thanks for the answer. i will keep this in mind. what I am trying to achieve here is to follow the open closed principle.